# complex solutions

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all $|z|=1$ such that $|z^4+4| = \sqrt{5}.$

---

I've tried doing
$$|z^4+4|^2 = 5 \implies (z^4+4)(\overline{z^4}+4) = 5 \implies |z|^8 + 4(z^4+\overline{z^4}) 
 +11=0,$$
but i'm not sure how to solve that.

Comment: In your last equation it should be $|z|^8$, which is then $1$. Observe that if $z=e^{it}$, then $z^4+\overline{z^4}=2\cos(4t)$. From it should get directly that $\cos(4t)=-3/2$, where $t$ is the argument of $z$.

Comment: The last equation is $z^4+\dfrac{1}{z^4}+3=0$ which is a quadratic in $z^4$.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by simple geometry.

Let $z^4=w$

Using $|z^4|=|z|^4$, as $|z|=1$ then $|w|=1$.

Now $w$ satisfies two properties

- $|w+4|=\sqrt{5}$ and $|w|=1$, plotting in Argand plane we get that former is a circle with centre at $(-4,0)$ and radius $\sqrt{5}$
- while the latter is a circle with centre at $(0,0)$ and radius $1$.

Now the solutions exist on the Argand plane where these two circles intersect and it can be clearly observed that they do not intersect at all .
Hence no solution exists for the complex equations.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try defining a new variable $w = z^4$ so that the equation in terms of $w$ reads (correcting the $z^8$ term to $|z|^8$)

$$ |w|^2 + 4(w+\bar{w}) + 11 = 0.$$

There are probably multiple ways to solve this, but I would break $w$ into real and imaginary parts and solve, noting that since $|z|=1$, $|w|=1$. I imagine there's a more elegant approach. Then after solving for $w$, you can solve for $z$.

Comment: But this gives $8\Re(w)+12=0\implies\Re(w)=-3/2$ which is impossible if $|w|=1$.